# How to view old .vcg file in RVIZ?

Tags: ros, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all, I found some old ROS packages(written in fuerte or even older version of ROS)  where the outdated .vcg files are used to view the status of robot. I think it is very helpful to understand these packages if I can open these .vcg files in RVIZ.
Can someone tell me how to get it?
Thank you！

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191625/how-to-view-old-.vcg-file-in-rviz?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on 2014-09-01**:
I think a vcg-rviz conversion tool doesn't exist (yet?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no conversion tool for these old rviz files.

The ticket for creating a conversion tool was closed because Fuerte is no longer supported: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/656 . I suspect it would take a good developer 4-8 hours to write such a tool, but no one has needed it that badly.

I've generally had an older version of ROS installed somewhere, so I usually just open the old config in the old version of rviz and recreate it in the new version of rviz.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-09-03**:
Thank you very much!